# How do I get a border around these divs using css?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a progress indicator for a Gantt chart, showing actual progress against target progress, a bit like this:

[image]

The black bar is the target, and the red is actual progress.

Sample code (it's generated on the fly) is this:

```
<div style='border: 1px solid red; position:relative; text-align:right'>
       <div class='progressBarRed' style='width:40%; float:left'></div>
       <div class='progressBarEmpty' style='width:60%; float:left;'></div>
       <div class='progressBarTarget' style='width:75%;'></div>
 </div>
```

and the CSS is:

```
/* Gant Bar
-----------------------------------------------*/

    div.progressBarEmpty
    {
        height:18px;
        position:relative;
        background: #dddddd;
    }

    div.progressBarGreen
    {
        position:relative;
        top:0px;left:0px;
        height:18px;
        background: #009900;
        z-index:0;

    }
    div.progressBarRed
    {
        position:relative;
        top:0px;left:0px;
        height:18px;
        background: #ee0000;
        z-index:0;

    }

    div.progressBarTarget
    {
        position:absolute;
        top:7px;left:0px;
        height:4px;
        background-color:#000000;
        border-style: none;
        z-index:1;
    }
```

The problem I'm having is that I can't get the red border to sit around the bars, like this:

[image]

It works with an empty bar, but when I introduce the red bar (and the float) the border collapses.

JSFiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/bdgriffiths/funnx3uz/

Comment: Have you tried specifying "!important" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `overflow: auto;` style to your div:

```
<div style='border: 1px solid red; overflow: auto; position:relative; text-align:right'>
       <div class='progressBarRed' style='width:40%; float:left'></div>
       <div class='progressBarEmpty' style='width:60%; float:left;'></div>
       <div class='progressBarTarget' style='width:75%;'></div>
 </div>
```

Basically if You are using "`float` div" inside another div it causes that inner div's height (with `float` style) is not added to outter div's height so in Your example the outter div has 0 height. `overflow` causes that it's inner div's height is added to outter div's height.

Answer (score 2):

You can make the same with just one element. Add `z-index: -1;` to the pseudo-element to take it to the bottom of everything.

Hover over the bar to see the red progress bar.

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6pogrdfp/)**

```css
div {
    height: 25px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
div:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 5px;
    width: 75%;
    top: 10px;
    background-color: black;
}
div:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0%;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: -1;
}
div:hover:after {
    width: 75%;
    transition: 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```